# How to make an image from a screenshot more clear?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, image-processing

I took screenshot for an image have numbers I couldn't see any of this numbers when I insert it in LibreOffice. How can I make this image more clear?

What are some applications in Ubuntu that can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the image in GIMP image editor (`sudo apt install gimp`). The problem is that the green circles are too bright to easily read the white text inside the circles. Select *Colors* -> *Hue-Saturation* -> change the *Saturation* slider from 0 to -50. Decreasing the saturation makes the colors less bright. Then select *File* -> *Overwrite name-of-original-image* to save the changes in the original image.

Here are the results which show that there is no problem reading the white text inside the green circles now. Click the image to enlarge it, so it can be seen more clearly:

[image: Results]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help, when taking screen shot in browser use extension. I use extension Nimbus Screenshot in Mozilla to take screenshot. Whatever you see same comes in that screenshot clear and visible.

Comment: thanks but excuse me i didn't get it well , how can i use extension ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get image on google, maybe I can help to advice you how get clearer image:

1. Make sure that image have a high resolution. To get it, click on image and click view image[image: like this]
2. After clicked on it, image will loaded larger. Then you can click left mouse, copy the image and paste it to libre office[image: paste it on writer]

**Note**: If you want to get image from website, click that image. After the image larger (occupied your browser's tab fully), then copy or screenshot it. The key for clearer image is high resolution.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for helping , i'm already took screen shot for that image and it's clear when i open it but after inserted it in libre office it became not clear !

Comment: Don't screenshot, copy it first (after the image goes larger) and paste it to libre office. Can I get link to your image so I can help?

Comment: i hope that but after i submitted data i took screen shoot the image and to  copy it first need me to submit the data again and it's hard to do that. is there any alternative solution ?

Comment: check this link: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BqBXiFwCcAAEh4G.png:large perhaps it was larger image than yours. I hope you can save or copy and paste it to writer

Comment: what if the image like what i posted it ? it's large but i inserted it in libre office still not clear

Comment: I tried to view, copy, and pasted it to writer. Then change page to landscape. Here's the result http://imgur.com/eHpt6Bj , did it still not clear enough for you?

Comment: First thanks for your help . but unfortuantly yes , it's still not clear . i hope i can make it more clear.  can i use photoshop or any filter ? or it will not help !